# Print a Cantor Set

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, fractal

### The Challenge

Build a N-Leveled [Cantor Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

> The Cantor ternary set is created by repeatedly deleting the open
>   middle thirds of a set of line segments.

The program receives one parameter `N` (a integer number) and then prints (in console or similar way) a Cantor Set of N levels. The print can only contain undescore (`_`) and whithe spaces characters. The parameter can be positive or negative and the sign indicates the Cantor Set construction orientation: If `N > 0` the Cantor Set is constructed downwards and if `N < 0` the Cantor Set is constructed upwards. If `N = 0` then the program prints a single line (`_`).

For example:

N = 2

```
_________
___   ___
_ _   _ _
```

N = -2

```
_ _   _ _
___   ___
_________
```

N = 3

```
___________________________
_________         _________
___   ___         ___   ___
_ _   _ _         _ _   _ _
```

N = -3

```
_ _   _ _         _ _   _ _
___   ___         ___   ___
_________         _________
___________________________
```

### Winning criteria

As it is a code golf challenge, the shortest code wins.

Edited: Modify 0 input by ugoren's suggestion.

Comment: Why print nothing when N=0? This makes 0 a special case, and makes it harder to use recursion. General handling would be to print a single `_` (but print it downward when getting -0).

Comment: Right. I have modified the specs already.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### GolfScript, <strike>49 42</strike> 40 chars

```
~.abs.3\?'_'*\{.3%..,' '*\++}*](0>2*(%n*
```

With thanks to [hammar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1811/hammar) for 42->40.

My best attempt yet at a more number-theoretic approach is sadly much longer:

```
~.abs:^3\?,{3^)?+3base(;1+1?.'_'*^@-)' '*+}%zip\0>2*(%n*
```

or

```
~.abs 3\?:^,{6^*+3base.1+1?.('_'*@,@-' '*+}%zip\0>2*(%n*
```

and I suspect that the length of `base` and `zip` will make it impossible to catch up.

Comment: `~.abs.@/\.3\?'_'*\{.3%..,' '*\++}*](%n*` is 39 chars, but crashes on input `0`. :-(

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, yes, division by zero was a pain for the C implementation I wrote too, because it meant you can't do `n/abs(n)` to get `signum(n)`.

Comment: https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v04vMalYzzjGXj1eXSumWs9YVU9PR10ByNbWrtWK1TCwM9LSUM3T@v/fFAA Output is a bit wonky at n=5.

Answer (score 7):

### Python, <strike>116 113 104</strike> 103 chars

```
n=input()
d=n>0 or-1
for i in range(n*d+1)[::d]:
 s='_'*3**i
 while i<n*d:s+=len(s)*' '+s;i+=1
 print s
```

Older algorithm topped out at 113 characters

```
r=input()
u='_'
l=[u]
for _ in abs(r)*u:o=len(l[0]);l=[s+o*' '+s for s in l]+[u*o*3]
print'\n'.join(l[::r>0 or-1])
```

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby (97)

Based on Steven Rumbalski's python version:

```rb
n,r=$*[0].to_i,[?_]
n.abs.times{z=r[0].size;r=r.map{|s|s+' '*z+s}+[?_*z*3]}
puts n<0?r:r.reverse
```

### Previous attempts, both same length (112)

Build lines from parts:

```rb
c=->x,n{n<1??_*x :(z=c[s=x/3,n-1])+' '*s+z}
r=(0..m=(n=$*[0].to_i).abs).map{|i|c[3**m,i]}
puts n<0?r.reverse: r
```

Start with one line, make holes in it:

```rb
r=[?_*3**a=(n=$*[0].to_i).abs]
a.times{|c|r<<r[-1].gsub((x=?_*o=3**(a-c-1))*3,x+' '*o+x)}
puts n<0?r.reverse: r
```

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>32</s> 31 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```apl
{' _'[⊖⍣(0>⍵)∧⍀1⍪1≠3⊥⍣¯1⍳3*|⍵]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/6vVFeLVox91TXvUu1jDwO5R71bNRx3LH/U2GD7qXWX4qHOB8aOupUC5Q@uBApuNtWqAKmJr/6cBNT/q7XvU1XxovfGjtolAA4ODnIFkiIdn8P80BQMuIBuoRkFdQZ0rTcEQlQs0DFXACF0eTcAYXd4YAA)

Saved 1 byte thanks to Adám by changing the conditional flipping `⊖⍣(0>⍵)` to *inside* the indexing.

**How it works**:

This answer builds on the mathematical properties of the Cantor set itself. It is known that a number is in the Cantor set iff its ternary expansion contains no 1s. So what we do is discretize the interval [0, 1], compute the ternary expansion of the numbers in there, check which ones have a 1 in their ternary expansion and exclude them from the subsequent iterations of the drawing.

```apl
{' _'[⊖⍣(0>⍵)∧⍀1⍪1≠3⊥⍣¯1⍳3*|⍵]}   ⍝ dfn expecting an integer as right argument (e.g. 2)
                         ⍳3*|⍵     ⍝ discretize the interval (e.g. 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
                   3⊥⍣¯1           ⍝ compute the ternary expansion in columns (e.g.
                                   ⍝    0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2
                                   ⍝    0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 )
               1⍪1≠                ⍝ find which numbers are ≠ from 1 and
                                   ⍝ append a row of 1s (e.g.
                                   ⍝    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
                                   ⍝    1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
                                   ⍝    1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 )
             ∧⍀                    ⍝ propagate the 0s downwards (e.g. 
                                   ⍝    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
                                   ⍝    1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
                                   ⍝    1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 )
      ⊖⍣(0>⍵)                     ⍝ mirror if the input number is negative
 ' _'[                        ]    ⍝ and index into ' _' to draw
```

Comment: `^⍀` is a nice strategy.

Comment: @Razetime scans with `<≤=≥>≠∨∧⍱⍲` are great to deal with Boolean vectors

Comment: 30: `{' _'[⊖⍣(0>⍵)×⍀1≠⍉↑,⍳1,3⍴⍨|⍵]}`

Comment: 28: `0∘>{' _'[⊖⍣⍺×⍀1≠⍉↑,⍳1,⍵⍴3]}|`

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 93 chars

```
@x=($t=$x=_ x 3**($a=abs($n=<>)),map$x.=$"x($x=~s/(.)../$1/g).$x,1..$a);say for$n<0?sort@x:@x
```

I thought I'd try to see how well [Peter Taylor's GolfScript solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4795) would port to Perl.  Notable features include the use of `sort` instead of `reverse` to save three chars, using the fact that a space sorts before `_`.

Answer (score 2):

### C, <strike>219</strike> <strike>193</strike> <strike>179</strike> <strike>143</strike> <strike>136</strike> 131 characters

Followed another of Petyer Taylor's ideas, plus an improvement of my own, saved 6 more.
Integrated some tips from @PeterTaylor, plus copied his main function, with slight changes, which save a character (is it fair to copy it? Since neither of us will win this one, I guess it isn't too bad).
I thought of a significant improvement in how my recursion works, and after seeing Peter Taylor's answer, I implemented it to regain the lead. When reading his answer again, I saw that I did almost exactly what he did. So this seems like the hybridization he suggested.
Also simplified the loop in `main`, keeping the same length.
And took Peter's trick to print newline, instead of `puts("")` - saves a character.

Removed `int` from variable declaration - a warning, but saves 4 chars.
New algorithm doesn't calculate 3^x in advance, but uses a single loop to print 3^x characters.
Can save one more by defining `int*v`, but then 64bit won't work.
Characters count excludes whitespace (which can be removed).

```
o,i,n;
p(c) {
    n-- ?
        p(c),p(o>n?c:32),p(c)
    :
        putchar(c);
    n++;
}
main(c,v)int**v; {
    for(n=abs(c=atoi(v[1]));i<=n;i++)o=c+n?n-i:i,p(95),puts("");
}
```

Older algorithm, 219 chars:

```
p(l,o,i,m,c,j) {
    for(;i<(m=l);i++)
        for(j=0,c=95;m/o||!putchar(c);j++)
            i/m%3-1||(c=32),m/=3;
    puts("");
}
main(c,v,n,i,l,o)int**v;{
    (n=atoi(v[1]))<0?n=-n:(c=0);
    for(i=n,l=1;i;i--)l*=3;
    o=c?1:l;
    for (;i<=n;i++)p(l,o,0),c?o*=3:(o/=3);
}
```

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I can't remove the `i` parameter, because using the global would interfere with `main`. `l--` will interfere with `o>=l`, and I'll have to replace it with `>` (so why do I write it as if it's a bad thing?) I could also copy you `main`, which is simpler and shorter than mine.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, you were right about `i` - I missed the fact that I really no longer use it (I thought you mean I don't pass it).

Comment: By the way, I don't mind you taking my main function. My rule of thumb is that copying someone else's solution to change a single character is overly aggressive, copying someone else's solution to rewrite half of it is perfectly fair, and there's a grey area somewhere in between. We should perhaps try to agree some community standards on meta.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I think we reached a sort of stalemate. My `p` seems quite optimal now, and your `main` was better (I'm not sure it's optimal, but can't improve it further). So except for a new ingenious program structure, the only way to go was either of us copying the other's code.

Comment: BTW How are you counting your characters? Because I make your latest version 138 chars, not 136.

Comment: And I can see how to save one more to 137: `o,i,l;p(c){l--?p(c),p(o>l?c:32),p(c):putchar(c);l++;}main(c,v,n)int**v;{for(;i<=(l=n=abs(c=atoi(v[1])));i++)o=c+n?n-i:i,p(95),l=0,p(10);}`

Comment: After joining everything to one line, `wc` says 137, but it counts the `\n`. `l++` is nice - makes me wonder what the stack is for. And I thought my `p` wasn't the place to make progress...

Answer (score 2):

### C (<strike>163</strike> 161 chars)

```
i,l,N;f(n,m,s){if(n){s=--n<l?m:s;f(n,m,s);f(n,s,s);f(n,m,s);}else
putchar(m);}main(n,v)int**v;{for(i=N=abs(n=atoi(1[v]));i+1;i--)l=n<N?N-i:i,f(N,95,32),f(0,10);}
```

Borrows a couple of tricks from [ugoren's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4796/194), but the core logic is quite different. I couldn't follow his for loop, so it may be possible to hybridise and save a few more.

Answer (score 2):

### Common Lisp, <strike>217</strike> 210 characters

```
(defun m(x)(flet((c(n v)(if(= n 0)`((,v))(cons(substitute v nil(make-list(expt 3 n)))(mapcar #'append(c(1- n)v)(c(1- n)" ")(c(1- n)v))))))(format t "~{~{~a~}~%~}"(let((r(c(abs x)'_)))(if(< x 1)(reverse r)r)))))
```

**Expanded:**

```
(defun m(x)
  (flet((c(n v)
    (if(= n 0)
       `((,v))
       (cons(substitute v nil(make-list(expt 3 n)))
            (mapcar #'append
                    (c(1- n)v)
                    (c(1- n)" ")
                    (c(1- n)v))))))
   (format t "~{~{~a~}~%~}"(let((r(c(abs x)'_)))(if(< x 1)(reverse r)r)))))
```

I figure if the Lisp code manages to beat any initial count for another language (C, 219) I'm doing OK :)

Answer (score 2):

## J, <s>44</s> <s>39</s> <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
' _'{~0&>_&(]|.)(,:1)1&(,],.0&*,.])~|
```

Uses iteration to build the next set starting with 1 (representing `_`) initially.

### Usage

```
   f =: ' _'{~0&>_&(]|.)(,:1)1&(,],.0&*,.])~|
   f 0
_
   f 1
___
_ _
   f _1
_ _
___
   f 2
_________
___   ___
_ _   _ _
   f _2
_ _   _ _
___   ___
_________
   f 3
___________________________
_________         _________
___   ___         ___   ___
_ _   _ _         _ _   _ _
   f _3
_ _   _ _         _ _   _ _
___   ___         ___   ___
_________         _________
___________________________
```

### Explanation

```
' _'{~0&>_&(]|.)(,:1)1&(,],.0&*,.])~|  Input: integer n
                                    |  Absolute value of n
                (,:1)                  The array [1]
                     1&(          )~   Repeat abs(n) times starting with x = [1]
                                 ]       Identity function, gets x
                            0&*          Multiply x by 0
                               ,.        Join the rows together
                         ]               Identity function, gets x
                          ,.             Join the rows together
                     1  ,                Prepend a row of 1's and return
      0&>                              Test if n is negative, 1 if true else 0
         _&(   )                       If n is negative
             |.                          Reverse the previous result
            ]                            Return that
                                       Else pass the previous result unmodified
' _'                                   The string ' _'
    {~                                 Select from the string using the result
                                       as indices and return
```

Comment: Nice! I haven't personally tried,  but I love using the agenda `@.`--perhaps it, combined with `$:`, could be of some use here? E.g. something like ``(zero case)`(positive case)`(negative case)@.*``, or even maybe ``":@_:`(positive case)`(|."1@$:)@.*``.

Comment: I haven't attempted a recursive solution, but I could try it.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>141 139</s> 137 bytes

```r
m=abs(n<-scan());write("if"(n<m,rev,c)(c(" ","_")[Reduce(`%x%`,rep(list(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,0,1),3)),m),t(1))[,1+2^m-2^(m:0)]+1]),1,3^m,,"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrNCsIwEAZfRRYK@9ENNK0nf17Ca2ltjRECbpE0at8@BmRuMxNz1vN8W3k5mdXNCwPHbwzJM4UHFasS/Ucc2DHtSOhK6C/@/naep2qrppJf/AxrYp1TDFv5rPxpxEI6QBSS2AK92Lod1bQj66HBUNsB5etGFSFCNvv8Aw)

-15 bytes thanks too Giuseppe's use of `'('` as the identity function; `write` instead of `cat` to print output; clever use of`%x%`.

-2 bytes thanks to Kirill L. by using `c` instead of `'('` as the identity function.

Comment: could a Kronecker product work here? `%x%`? There might be some issues with taking alternating rows perhaps...

Comment: @Giuseppe I tried, building on your "Create an “H” from smaller “H”s" answer... I'll give it another try.

Comment: Ah, so it was you who upvoted that. that's the only reason I thought of `kron` too! I'd imagine this should be able to go down to like 125 bytes if we can find the right approach.

Comment: you can use `\`(\`` as the identity function so you can use `write` directly instead of `cat` and a `for` loop. [141 bytes](https://tio.run/##TYw7DsIwEAV7ToG22pWeBZHbhKNAPsTRFiySscG3N5ZCQfmeZibWbagh25L0aWzyiZpWJg3Edjlj5BFxfQsHLr2b5ldDRNDBXwtAJIcw/NlxVrv/bCz7uBH2O/cusLlO8JhS1MJ0pNaxk4cJcss2VqRu7KV@AQ)

Comment: @Giuseppe I had no idea `(` could be used this way, or that `if ` could be used to select from two functions. And I will start using write... saves a lot of "\n".

Comment: I think, you can also use just `c` instead of `(` as identity for -2 bytes, like I did [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165352/78274)

Comment: @KirillL. @Giuseppe `c` does work!

Comment: Aha! [137 bytes using `%x%`!](https://tio.run/##JYrNCoMwEAZfpSwI@@EGjN768xK9ilabphDoisS09e3TQJnbzMSc9TLfN17OZnPzwsDpG0PyTOFJxapE/xEHdkwHEroR@qt/vJ3nqdqrqeSVX2FLrHOKYS@flT@NWEgHiEISW6AXW7ejmnZkPTYYajugfN2oIkTIps0/) Note that your above answer could be 137 bytes as a full program as well.

Comment: @Giuseppe this is just wow.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, <strike>177</strike> 164 characters

```
N=input()
n=abs(N)
c=lambda x:0if x<1 else x%3==1or c(x/3)
r=["".join([["_"," "][c(x/3**i)]for x in range(3**n)])for i in range(n+1)]
print"\n".join(r[::N>0 or-1])
```

Comment: Since you are using Python 2 you don't need to cast the results of `input` as `int`.  Your last two lines could be shortened to `print"\n".join(r[::N>0 or-1])`

Comment: @Steven I made changes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 113 chars

```
$i=abs($I=<>);@w=$_='_'x3**$i;while($i--){$x=3**$i;s/(__){$x}/'_'x$x.' 'x$x/eg;push@w,$_}say for$I>0?reverse@w:@w
```

**Expanded:**

```
$i=abs($I=<>);
@w=$_='_'x3**$i;
while($i--){
    $x=3**$i;
    s/(__){$x}/'_'x$x.' 'x$x/eg;
    push@w,$_
}
say for$I>0?reverse@w:@w
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, <s>265</s> <s>262</s> <s>242</s> <s>236</s> 235 bytes

```
@echo off
set/pn=
set c=%n%,-1,0
if %n% lss 0 set c=0,1,%n:-=%
for /l %%i in (%c%)do call:l %%i
exit/b
:l
set s=_
for /l %%j in (1,1,%n:-=%)do call:m %1 %%j
echo %s%
:m
set t=%s%
if %1 lss +%2 set t=%s:_= %
set s=%s%%t%%s%
```

Edit: Saved <s>12</s> 19 bytes thanks to @l4m2. Saved 8 bytes by removing the unnecessary `%a%` variable.

Comment: [This](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%40echo%20off%0Aset%20Q%3D%29%20do%20call%3A%0Aset%2Fpn%3D%0Aset%20a%3D%25n%3A-%3D%25%0Aif%20%25n%25%20lss%200%20for%20%2Fl%20%25%25i%20in%20%280%2C1%2C%25a%25%25Q%25l%20%25%25i%0Afor%20%2Fl%20%25%25i%20in%20%28%25n%25%2C-1%2C0%25Q%25l%20%25%25i%0Aexit%2Fb%0A%3Al%0Aset%20s%3D%5f%0Afor%20%2Fl%20%25%25j%20in%20%281%2C1%2C%25a%25%25Q%25m%20%251%20%25%25j%0Aecho%20%25s%25%0Aexit%2Fb%0A%3Am%0Aset%20t%3D%25s%25%0Aif%20%251%20lss%20%252%20set%20t%3D%25s%3A%5f%3D%20%25%0Aset%20s%3D%25s%25%25t%25%25s%25) for 247 bytes.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Mind you it would be 261 if I counted all the CRs as well as the LFs (which I'm sure you're not required to do but I'm lazy like that).

Comment: So you're not removing CR's from your code? Even though it's not required by .BAT files and stripped by SE anyhow? :P

Comment: @ConorO'Brien It's a penalty I accept of using Notepad to write Batch files.

Comment: Can you do something like `set c=%n%,-1,0 [LF] 
if %n% lss 0 set c=0,1,%a% [LF] 
for /l %%i in (%c%)do call:l %%i`?

Comment: @l4m2 Thanks, in fact it turns out I don't even need `%a%`.

Comment: seems also fine to let `l` jump into `m`

Comment: @l4m2 Won't work because `m` expects `%1` and `%2` to be numeric.

Comment: @Neil If you decide to count crlf as 2 bytes you should turn some newline into `&`(should try to golf)

Comment: @l4m2 Numbers beginning with 0 are treated as octal.

Comment: @Neil what about https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mWCTRrXf9Q/

Comment: @l4m2 Yes that works thanks.

Comment: Can `if %1 lss +%2 set t=%s:_= %` workwithout the added zero before?

Comment: @l4m2 Both `+1` and `-1` are greater than `+` and `-`... WTF?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78071/discussion-between-l4m2-and-neil).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript 121 bytes

Inner recursive function, then take care of backward output if needed

```js
n=>(f=(n,t=n&&f(n-1),r=t[0])=>n?[r+r+r,...t.map(x=>x+t[n]+x)]:['_',' '],f=f(n<0?-n:n),f.pop(),n<0?f.reverse():f).join`\n`
```

*Less golfed*

```js
n=>{
  var f = n => { // recursive function
    var t = n && f(n-1), r = t[0]
    return n 
      ? [r+r+r, ...t.map(x => x+t[n]+x)]
      : ['_',' ']
  };
  f = f(n < 0 ? -n : n);
  f.pop(); // last row is all blanks
  if (n<0) f.reverse();
  return f.join`\n`
}
```

**Test**

```js
var F=
n=>(f=(n,t=n&&f(n-1),r=t[0])=>n?[r+r+r,...t.map(x=>x+t[n]+x)]:['_',' '],f=f(n<0?-n:n),f.pop(),n<0?f.reverse():f).join`\n`

function go()
{
  var n=+I.value
  O.textContent = F(n)
}

go()
```

```html
<input id=I type=number value=3 oninput='go()'>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 111 bytes

```powershell
filter f{if($s=[math]::Sign($_)){($x=$_-$s|f|%{$_+' '*($l=$_|% Le*)+$_})|?{$s-1};'_'*3*$l;$x|?{$s+1}}else{'_'}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzLCsMgFAX3@QoJN/iIQo1dJYT@QOmmy1KkC20C9kEMNKB@u5Wc1TAH5vv5mcVPxrmc7exWsyAbZkvAj7fXY53ufX@dn28CmtJAYBtBC/DRxiaAbjHCjIArMjbobBhtQScaTwG8kGnAGjPFwA2w7a6VKRnnTShHSvnAJReSd1x0XHGh@LFUK1RWX0qy3rGk7Q4YVyn/AQ)

Less golfed:

```powershell
filter f{
    if($sign=[math]::Sign($_)){
        $x=$_-$sign|f|%{
            $_+' '*($length=$_|% Length)+$_
        }
        $x|?{$sign-1}  # output $x if $_ is negative
        '_'*3*$length
        $x|?{$sign+1}  # output $x if $_ is positive
    }
    else{
        '_'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 31 bytes

```
*±¹↑→a¹¡oṁ§ṘȯJ' R2←o/3LgR'_`^3a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9odXNr//8qwrHCueKGkeKGkmHCucKhb@G5gcKn4bmYyK9KJyBSMuKGkG8vM0xnUidfYF4zYf///y00)

Doesn't really use the cantor set, just uses a replacement method (and an infinite list).

Now, you may ask: why is an infinite list useful here? Here's an explanation:

### Explanation

```
¡oṁ§ṘȯJ' R2←o/3LgR'_`^3a
                       a take abs(n) 
                 R'_`^3 repeat underscore n times(take n=3)
¡o                      iterate on this string, collecting results
                g       group the string into equal runs:
                        ["_________"]
  ṁ                     map each group to the following, and concatenate:
         R2←            repeat the first character twice
      J'                join with spaces
                        "_________" → "_ _"
            o/3L        take length /3 → 3
   §Ṙ                   Repeat each character that many times
                        "___   ___"

Then:
   ↑→a¹ take n+1 elements from the list
*±¹     multiply by sign(n) (reverse if negative)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 148 bytes

```javascript
n=>f=(L=n<0&&n,R=n>0&&n)=>[...Array(r=3**(n>0?n:-n))].map(_=>((j++).toString(3)+1).indexOf(1)>(L>0?L:-L)?'_':' ',j=r+r).join``+`
${L++<R?f(L,R):''}`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3LCsIwEADvfkUPYnbNA6u36qZ48RQQ6lHEFm2lRTcSgyjit1fF28AwTFfdq9shtNeo2R/rfpVQ0jPZhsARLyajEauC2P4AyW6NMcsQqicEmo3H8BU5Z5oRd@ZSXWFPFqCTEk30mxhaPsEMZYqm5WP9WDeQogX3jVymHeZiLzKRCNVRkAFN51suS1kOhi8n5aLIG3CqwEyId9nPB1s9VTpVE5Wq6X8XyR483/y5Nmd/ghVEBETsPw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 102 bytes

```python
lambda n:'\n'.join(eval("[i+' '*len(i)+i for i in"*abs(n)+"'_'"+"]+['___'*len(i)]"*abs(n))[::n<1or-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcrBCgIhEADQXxm8jLNSsNFJ6ktcEZdWmrBRXAv6ejvt@b36688il5Huy8jxvT4iiMVF8PwqLHr7xqyVY4OAU95EMxmGVBowsKgprrsWMgoDKqO8cRhCOKY/nJy1cptLO82eRm0sHZJmqZ@uicb1Dw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>265</s> <s>232</s> 213 bytes

```
S-E-R:-between(S,E,R).
[]/R/R.
[H|T]/B/R:-T/[H,32,H|B]/R.
N+R:-(N>0->O is N-1,O+S,S/[]/R;R=`_`).
N*[H|T]:-1-N-_,writef("%n",[H]);N*T.
_*[]:-nl.
-N:-(0-N-J,K is N-J;N-0-I,J is -I,K is I-N),L is 3^K,J+R,L*R,1=0;1=1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxNC4JAEIbv/goJAldndt3spFggCGYxwepNzAgsBNGowEv/3Xbt9M77Mc/zNfbjA99TN88FpqhCvLWfqW0Hp4AUFONWVQsllNbsW9YiEXpSiiqDYAPZN6lNRZ4OHdr5uDvb3dsmlHD2CiiEeY5UfG2umkTuwghRImED06v7tHdntR5WUGU1i8gtudW4lV4MPbeQNNTX0xyOf2oeEfp4gNxYrUt8QGJwMldwOULuKTi5CmTsRzKWfN6jjc6WgW2Qi8GA8fkH)

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 243 bytes

```
|i:i8|(0..i.abs() as usize).any(|j|print!("{}
",if i>0{f(j,3usize.pow(i as u32-1))}else{f(-i as usize-j-1,3usize.pow(-i as u32-1))})>());fn f(i:usize,j:usize)->String{if i<1{"_".repeat(j)}else{[f(i-1,j/3)," ".repeat(j/3),f(i-1,j/3)].concat()}}
```

Once again I win the prize for the longest answer

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY9BTsMwEEX3PYXxakaKTdNsqpbmEiwRQqayo7GKG8WOKnByEjZZwAFYcxLOwQVwkorC6mvmv5k_8_rWtD4MH8axJ0UOkMWDDqzavbfBiPXXd0cbWnewlJKkevQJUJ61nl40SuWeobNd3ZALV8Bjv-AZGUblMhqwWTFhsj6egKapYiVyxF4fvE6AoN9Vwor8Ly7-8VgC4jZdaIA2E5TZWVGUtyGlV3GMvckjf-Cy0bVWAew56C5Npe32usCMs4s91hfrXu6Pbp_62Pfz658VrHC7qEDMUszFKGdiGGb9AQ)

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 247 bytes

```
|x:i32|->String{let r=(0..x.abs() as u32).map(|d|{(0..3_usize.pow(x.abs() as u32-1)).map(move|w|if(0..d).all(|v|w/3_usize.pow(x.abs() as u32-2-v)%3!=1){'_'}else{' '}).chain(['\n'])});if x<0{r.rev().flatten().collect()}else{r.flatten().collect()}};
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fY9NTsMwFIT3nMKthOwnEdMmm6ohXIJlQZVJnWDJ-ZHt_AjbJ2GTBRyA43AStiRNN4iI1ZNmvtG8eXtXjTbDZ1aigomSALKSG5QnH43Jgt3Xt-v3IgpdcP9glCjzs6sSsqG0p-xZjwGmUROFQAtWE3dydvKiY6PFK6d11ZHfXLCFGS2qlrvOiWziT0CZlMS1rrv9JxsGLVxHq2QLFh-x51JzixH2QNOX6fsDfizxE3iIRYb6u41VVPGWAM0kM4aP82haSclTQ2BOq0XLx5f5h3ocbWS5Imvr1zcoJyFAfPVHDZblaBk-y36uGIb5_gA)