# Generalized Cantor set segment lengths

Tags: code-golf, sequence, fractal, recursion

## Problem

Let's define a generalized [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) by iteratively deleting some rational length segments from the middle of all intervals that haven't yet been deleted, starting from a single continuous interval.

Given the relative lengths of segments to delete or not, and the number of iterations to do, the problem is to write a [program or function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/60340) that outputs the relative lengths of the segments that have or have not been deleted after `n` iterations.

[image: Example 3,1,1,1,2]

Example: Iteratively delete the 4th and 6th eighth

## Input:

`n` – number of iterations, indexed starting from 0 or 1

`l` – list of segment lengths as positive integers with `gcd(l)=1` and odd length, representing the relative lengths of the parts that either stay as they are or get deleted, starting from a segment that doesn't get deleted. Since the list length is odd, the first and last segments never get deleted.
For example for the regular Cantor set this would be [1,1,1] for one third that stays, one third that gets deleted and again one third that doesn't.

## Output:

Integer list `o`, `gcd(o)=1`, of relative segment lengths in the `n`th iteration when the segments that weren't deleted in the previous iteration are replaced by a scaled down copy of the list `l`. The first iteration is just `[1]`. You can use any unambiguous [output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/60340) method, even unary.

## Examples

```
n=0, l=[3,1,1,1,2] →                 [1]
n=1, l=[3,1,1,1,2] →     [3,    1,    1,    1,    2]
n=2, l=[3,1,1,1,2] → [9,3,3,3,6,8,3,1,1,1,2,8,6,2,2,2,4]

n=3, l=[5,2,3]     → [125,50,75,100,75,30,45,200,75,30,45,60,45,18,27]
n=3, l=[1,1,1]     → [1,1,1,3,1,1,1,9,1,1,1,3,1,1,1]
```

You can assume the input is valid. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program measured in bytes wins.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to input and output the indices of non-deleted segments instead of the lengths?  For instance, `[0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7]` instead of `[3, 1, 1, 1, 2]`?

Comment: @Mnemonic it's not too far from unary, so I'd say it's fine.

Comment: Could you add one (or multiple) test case(s) for even-sized input-lists?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen the input lists are guaranteed to be odd-sized

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>15 13</s>  12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-2 thanks to Dennis (using a Link rather than a chain allows right to be used implicitly by `¡`; No need to wrap the `1` in a list due to the fact that Jelly prints lists of one item the same as the item)
-1 thanks to Erik the Outgolfer (use `Ɗ` to save the newline from using `Ç`)

```
1×€³§JḤ$¦ẎƊ¡
```

A full program printing a list in Jelly format (so `[1]` is printed as `1`)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//w5figqzCs8KnSuG4pCTCpuG6jgoxw4fCof///1s1LDIsM13/Mw)**

#### How?

```
1×€³§JḤ$¦ẎƊ¡ - Main link: segmentLengths; iterations
1            - literal 1 (start with a single segment of length 1)
           ¡ - repeat...
             - ...times: implicitly use chain's right argument, iterations
          Ɗ  - ...do: last 3 links as a monad (with 1 then the previous output):
   ³         - (1) program's 3rd argument = segmentLengths
 ×€          -  1  multiply €ach (e.g. [1,2,3] ×€ [1,2,1] = [[1,4,3],[2,4,2],[3,6,3]])
        ¦    -  2  sparse application... 
       $     - (2) ...to: indices: last two links as a monad:
     J       - (2)          range of length = [1,2,3,...,numberOfLists]
      Ḥ      - (2)          double            [2,4,6,...] (note: out-of bounds are ignored by ¦)
    §        - (2) ...of: sum each (i.e. total the now split empty spaces)
         Ẏ   -  3  tighten (e.g. [[1,2,3],4,[5,6,7]] -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
             - implicit print
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>120</s> <s>107</s> <s>104</s> <s>103</s> <s>100</s> <s>99</s> 89 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,l:n and[x*y for i,x in enumerate(l)for y in[f(n-1,l),[sum(l)**~-n]][i%2]]or[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7bCoMwDH3fVxTGQCVCL/M22JeUPnSoTNAoTkFf9uuuFpw618BJcnKS02bsnjXyacrvpa4eqSYI5Q2JxlQO3kjyuiUFDKRAkmFfZa3uMqd0Z3o0pMwd9BmULshXX5mB5719VEoWF65U3UqmpqYtsCO5Q0EKYDa4cs/k8Iz4tIjZP7Gh5sQOyNdF/rsoExA2QojhOzJ1aHCO67osQAaGEasj4wEEFKIAGLVJULgazbYJLbIYeLQ7Za02p6zz8oMEdr2aPg)

---

Saved

- -10 bytes, thanks to Neil

Comment: [89 bytes](https://tio.run/##bU7bCoMwDH3fVxTGQCVCL/M22JeUPnSoTNAoTkFf9uuuFpw618BJcnKS02bsnjXyacrvpa4eqSYI5Q2JxlQO3kjyuiUFDKRAkmFfZa3uMqd0Z3o0pMwd9BmULshXX5mB5719VEoWF65U3UqmpqYtsCO5Q0EKYDa4cs/k8Iz4tIjZP7Gh5sQOyNdF/rsoExA2QojhOzJ1aHCO67osQAaGEasj4wEEFKIAGLVJULgazbYJLbIYeLQ7Za02p6zz8oMEdr2aPg "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>76</s> 58 bytes

```hs
l%0=[1]
l%n=do(x,m)<-l%(n-1)`zip`cycle[l,[sum l]];map(*x)m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYpBCsIwEEX3OcUsDCSSQtPgyuYInmAINLQFg5M0WIXq5WPNQuRv3n@8q19vM1EpxFuL2jHiyU6L2FSUfUNcpEbL4R3yML5GmpEUrs8I5Nw5@iyOm4wl@pDAwrQw2N0F8j2kBxy@BwQapes6xyVgW4n9GjypThnHzZ@q/a7KBw)

The function `(%)` takes the list of line lengths `l` as first argument and the number of iterations `n` as second input.

*Thanks to Angs and Ørjan Johansen for -18 bytes!*

Comment: You should be able to save at least 7 bytes by switching to a recursion on `n` and dropping `#` altogether

Comment: Independently of @Angs 's suggestion, the original `%` can be shortened to `l%a=do(x,m)<-zip a$a>>[l,[sum l]];(*x)<$>m
`.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 94 bytes

```r
f=function(n,a)"if"(n,unlist(Map(function(g,i)g(i),c(c,sum),split(m<-a%o%f(n-1,a),row(m)))),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYwxCsMwDEX3HiMQkECB2qZbe4QewhgUBLEcYpse3xUZskR/0X9P6BiDP9w1NSkKShEn4cmWrpvUBt@4w6VXElxBkBIkqj0j1X2TBvm9xLnMDLo4@0BH@UFGG3I4GJ52H8id8YgPBncj/kaCkRd5Clc7LeL4Aw)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (Firefox 42-57), 80 bytes

```
f=(n,l,i=0)=>n--?[for(x of l)for(y of(i^=1)?f(n,l):[eval(l.join`+`)**n])x*y]:[1]
```

Needs those specific versions because it uses both array comprehensions and exponentiation.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 71 bytes

```javascript
l=>f=(n,c=1,e)=>n--?''+l.map(_=>(e=!e)?f(n,c*_):eval(l.join`+`)**n*c):c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrBDoIwDADQu3/hiXZsS8AbpuPGTxgDyywGUjsiht@f0bzrW@MR9/Reto/T/OAyUBEKM4HaRI1lpKDO9VVVi3/FDUYKwHRm7OdfMSN2fEQB8WtedKonNEZNwi6V6yll3bOwl/yEAW4X2/y1d4QWsXwB)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, 261 bytes

```java
L->n->{if(n<1){L.clear();L.add(1);}else if(n>1){var C=new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>(L);for(int l=C.size(),i,x,t,s;n-->1;)for(i=x=0;i<L.size();){t=L.remove(i);if(i%2<1)for(;i%-~l<l;)L.add(i,C.get((i++-x)%l)*t);else{x++;s=0;for(int c:C)s+=c;L.add(i++,t*s);}}}}
```

Modifies the input-List instead of returning a new one to save bytes.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##xVPBitswEL33K3QJaNayWCf0UtmGYigU3NMeSw@qI4dJFdlI4zSpSX89lb3ebim7e@lCJR3E6OnN07zRXh91ut9@uzZWh8A@aXTjG8YCacKG7eOpHAitbAfXEHZOflg2@ePZe@/1ucZA@UdHZmd8KZ66WXUuDAfjf6NK1rLiWqelS8sRW@7yDMZaNtZoz0HVUm@3PAN1MTYYNgHKCDhqz6rCme/sJQW8BtV2nqMjZotKBvxhOAgUJ0EiKJemZaZgRhSn4lZhXi8YBSMVtfTm0B0NR1AxMa7WUduEVrhKf9rcKriXh6KSO0OcY5KkJ1hZuCFQk@DxlCQqROoHGc27CkJSNMvD4gVBNyE@L46rikWPqx@@2lj3pfzHDrfsEC3hd@TR7T5/YRomexgjE4jfCvZMHfhfsSB1mOMbkc1zDQDqkSl7Nab1qzFt/ifTW7EWm39mmdUsLJd7h/@0dqadWsOJF5uZ1YvrrdR9b8@xuaVuGtMTd4vCu3Mgc5DdQLKPrULWTT9gTnu5/gI)

```java
L->n->{                       // Method with List and integer parameters and no return-type
  if(n<1){                    //  If `n` is 0:
    L.clear();                //   Remove everything from the List
    L.add(1);}                //   And only add a single 1
                              //  Else-if `n` is 1: Leave the List as is
  else if(n>1){               //  Else-if `n` is 2 or larger:
    var C=new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>(L);
                              //   Create a copy of the input-List
    for(int l=C.size(),       //   Set `l` to the size of the input-List
        i,x,t,s;              //   Index and temp integers
        n-->1;)               //   Loop `n-1` times:
      for(i=x=0;              //    Reset `x` to 0
          i<L.size();){       //    Inner loop `i` over the input-List
        t=L.remove(i);        //     Remove the current item, saving its value in `t`
        if(i%2<1)             //     If the current iteration is even:
          for(;i%-~l<l;)      //      Loop over the copy-List
            L.add(i,C.get((i++-x)%l)*t);
                              //       And add the values multiplied by `t`
                              //       at index `i` to the List `L`
        else{                 //     Else (the current iteration is odd):
          x++;                //      Increase `x` by 1
          s=0;for(int c:C)s+=c;
                              //      Calculate the sum of the copy-List
          L.add(i++,t*s);}}}} //      Add this sum multiplied by `t`
                              //      at index `i` to the List `L`
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
Ø1××S¥ƭ€³Ẏ$¡Ṗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9qZWxsef//w5gxw5fDl1PCpcat4oKswrPhuo4kwqHhuZb///9bNSwgMiwgM13/Mw)

Full program. Outputs `1` instead of `[1]`. Annoyingly, `ḋ` doesn't work like `×S¥` in this context, and `ƭ` doesn't work well with nilads. >_<

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 20 bytes

```apl
{(∊⊢×⍵(+/⍵)⍴⍨≢)⍣⍺,1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU07DoJQEOw5xXZAhMjjj7chGAyRBAM0xlBpjGBI7KzFxgNoQ@tN9iLPBX/wJpmd2Z3d569idb7242ShBrGfZVHAeYj700bCQ4VV8zxj/ZAmU2IZ6zvWNywbUlesW4UVnOddmKZYXlKSWG1DCrczMVmKeNyJoR/FIjUokhaCJhnAeuhyrjCBDT38tKCP@h5NOtjg/jOkbeIOpmBIFlUD6FGe6RZYGjgWMK0vhgYmBYbG7pm5oDu0/b752e7x/ccb@xc)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 27 bytes

```
{x{,/y*(#y)#x}[(y;+/y)]/,1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU3LCoMwELz3KxbsQVuLWWN87aeEgL1YimJBPBiD/fU0RhDLwOzMLLPbPYbXYG1bm9nEib6FgY6CeZWhpnuiI5XEuFo71eYql@9Yt3Imraj5dBQ27fPdk/O00Bip9TJJRhzQI6UYlUvwlBxqW5wsVcA9cijhSJ3OHW/ItgIn4SQnTAUIBoUAZH5wBplbnU3uGUtIi73qb@58fKjgz6sf)

`{` `}` is a function with arguments `x` and `y`

`(y;+/y)` a pair of `y` and its sum

`{` `}[(y;+/y)]` projection (aka currying or partial application) of a dyadic function with one argument. `x` will be `(y;+/y)` and `y` will be the argument when applied.

`,1` singleton list containing 1

`x{` `}[` `]/` apply the projection `x` times

`(#y)#x` reshape to the length of the current result, i.e. alternate between the outer `y` and its sum

`y*` multiply each element of the above with the corresponding element of the current result

`,/` concatenate

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 73 bytes

```ruby
->a,l{r=[1];a.times{s=p;r=r.flat_map{|x|(s=!s)?l.map{|y|x*y}:x*l.sum}};r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcnBCgIhFIXhfU9Ru2m4SSptEpsHEQmDhEBBrjOgqM9u5KbFcFb/d3B75W5lvzwMuIJSUS0MWT/@HUuUQaBEYp1Zn96EUlOdojzF8@LI6FzTnNs9zY7EzbcmsPVwtOoKigMdY1offkT3xPbEQd2AAf/n@LXuXw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
us.e?%k2*bsQ*LbQGE]1
```

Input is segment array `l`, then iterations `n`. Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=us.e%3F%25k2%2AbsQ%2ALbQGE%5D1&input=%5B3%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C2%5D%0A2&debug=0), or verify all the test cases at once [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=us.e%3F%25k2%2AbsQ%2ALbQGE%5D1&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B3%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C2%5D%0A0%0A%5B3%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C2%5D%0A1%0A%5B3%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C2%5D%0A2%0A%5B5%2C2%2C3%5D%0A3%0A%5B1%2C1%2C1%5D%0A3&debug=0&input_size=2).

```
us.e?%k2*bsQ*LbQGE]1   Implicit, Q=1st arg (segment array), E=2nd arg (iterations)
u                E     Execute E times, with current value G...
                  ]1   ... and initial value [1]:
  .e            G        Map G, with element b and index k:
        *bsQ               Multiply b and the sum of Q {A}
            *LbQ           Multiply each value of Q by b {B}
    ?%k2                   If k is odd, yield {A}, otherwise yield {B}
 s                       Flatten the resulting nested array
```